# ol.control.FullScreen label conflict

Tags: openlayers-3

I have recently ported my app from 3.1.1 to 3.20.0 and noticed a conflict in the label of the FullScreen control. The controls on my ol.Map look like this:

```
        this.map = new ol.Map({
            controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
                new ol.control.FullScreen(),
                new ol.control.ScaleLine({minWidth:100, target:$('#scale-line')[0]})
         ])
```

When I load my map, this is what the fullScreen control  [looks like when not yet in full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzWez.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oczr.png) what it looks like after fullscreen view is enabled.

Even if I try to force ol.control.FullScreen to support a customised label, such as a span containing the icon fa fa-expand, I still get the WEST-EAST overlapping arrows.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code and HTML. All I can say is that it works with plain FullScreen and ScaleLine controls. See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BRRWEq?&editors=1110.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out. I had left the old ol 3.1.1 css file instead of replacing it with the new ol.css. Once I did it, the Full screen icon changed as expected.

Very lame of me indeed.